# How i can calculate the correlation of each variable within the same grouping variable using dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr, correlation

Let's say  i have a financial historical dataset of 8 stocks that belong in 3 categories.I want to calculate the correlation of each stock within each group in R using the dplyr package.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidyquant)
Category = c("Social","Social","Internet","Technology",
             "Technology","Internet","Internet")
symbol = c("TWTR","FB","GOOG","TSLA","NOK","AMZN","AAPL")
A = tibble(Category,symbol)
B = tq_get(symbol, 
       from = "2021-01-01", 
       to = "2022-01-01")
BA = left_join(B,A,by="symbol")
BA%>%select(symbol,Category,close)
```

Few days ago i posted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72996783/how-i-can-calculate-correlation-between-each-variable-within-each-group-in-r-usi/72997301?noredirect=1#comment128950981_72997301) similar question but the grouping variable was numeric and i my real world data set does not apply. The ideal output would be like this :

| Category | Stock1 | Stock2 | cor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Social | TWTR | FB | cor(TWTR,FB) |
| Internet | GOOG | AMZN | cor(GOOG,AMZN) |
| Internet | GOOG | AAPL | cor(GOOG,AMZN) |
| Internet | AMZN | AAPL | cor(GOOG,AAPL) |
| Technology | TSLA | NOK | cor(TSLA,NOK) |

Any help of how i can do this in R using dplyr ?

**optional data**

```
var2 = c(rep("A",3),rep("B",3),rep("C",3),rep("D",3),rep("E",3),rep("F",3),
         rep("H",3),rep("I",3))

y2 = c(-1.23, -0.983, 1.28, -0.268, -0.46, -1.23,
       1.87, 0.416, -1.99, 0.289, 1.7, -0.455,
       -0.648, 0.376, -0.887,0.534,-0.679,-0.923,
       0.987,0.324,-0.783,-0.679,0.326,0.998);length(y2)
group2 = as.character(c(rep("xx",6),rep("xy",6),rep("xz",6),rep("xx",6)))
data2 = tibble(var2,group2,y2);data2
```

Comment: Since your question is not about quant data, can you please post sample data so that we don't have to install quantod/tidyquant?

Comment: @r2evans yes see the optional data that i added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple helper function,

```r
fun <- function(ticker, value, ...) {
  com <- combn(unique(ticker), 2)
  L <- split(value, ticker)
  data.frame(
    Stock1 = com[1,], Stock2 = com[2,],
    Corr = mapply(function(a, b) cor(a, b, ...), L[com[1,]], L[com[2,]])
  )
}
```

And the work:

```r
library(dplyr)
data2 %>%
  group_by(group2) %>%
  summarize(fun(var2, y2), .groups = "drop")
# # A tibble: 8 x 4
#   group2 Stock1 Stock2   Corr
#   <chr>  <chr>  <chr>   <dbl>
# 1 xx     A      B      -0.995
# 2 xx     A      H      -0.958
# 3 xx     A      I       0.853
# 4 xx     B      H       0.982
# 5 xx     B      I      -0.901
# 6 xx     H      I      -0.967
# 7 xy     C      D       0.469
# 8 xz     E      F      -0.186
```

Quick validation:

```r
cor(filter(data2, var2 == "A")$y2, filter(data2, var2 == "B")$y2)
# [1] -0.9949738
```

Comment: Thank you for your very useful answer as you always give .If the function of interest was not the correlation i.e cor() but the quantile of the difference of each pair how can be written/modified in the code above ? For example the quantile(A-B,0.99).What changes must be done in order to achieve it ?

Comment: Ummm ... replace `cor(a,b.,,,)` with `quantile(a-b,0.99,...)`?